# Simple Web Server Socket Program not working?

Tags: python, sockets, webserver

I'm currently doing a socket program for a simple web server that basically retrieves an HTML file from a server's file system. The server sets up perfectly and is ready to serve, however when I try to access the html file which in this case, "index.html" which is in the same directory as my WebServer.py, the browser keeps saying this page cannot be displayed. I've tried using different port numbers and different browsers to no avail.

Here is my code:

**WebServer.py**

```
from socket import *

def main():

    #Specify the port
    serverPort= 3000
    serverSocket=socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM)
    serverSocket.bind(('',serverPort))
    serverSocket.listen(1) #listen for connection
    print("Web server up on port",serverPort) #print port address

    #Start thw while loop.
    while True:

        print("Ready to serve")
        connectionSocket,addr = serverSocket.accept()
        try:

            message = connectionSocket.recv(1024)
            print message,'::', message.split()[0], ':', message.split()[1]
            filename = message.split()[1]

            print(filename,'||',filename[1:])
            f = open(filename[1:])
            outputdata = f.read()
            print outputdata

            connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 200 OK \r\n')
            connectionSocket.send(outputdata)
            connectionSocket.close()


        except IOError:
            pass
            #Send response message for the file not found.
            print ("404 Not Found")
            connectionSocket.send('HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \r\n');

        #Temp break
        break
    pass
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Could you please fix the code you show to be the same you actually use? There is no `messagesplit` but probably `message.split`. Also the indentation is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     connectionSocket.send('\nHTTP/1.1 200 OK\n\n')
> ```

The leading `\n` at the start of the HTTP header is definitely wrong. Apart from that the line delimiter should be `\r\n` not `\n`.

> ```
>     connectionSocket.send('\HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found \n\n');
> ```

This should be `HTTP/1.1...` and not `\HTTP/1.1...`. And the line delimiter is wrong too.

I have no idea where your (insufficient) understanding of HTTP comes from. But if you want to implement a server I recommend to not just have a look at a few packet captures or similar but actually study the standard which is more complex than you might imagine. That's what standards are for.

Comment: I changed the two lines and it's still not working. My "insufficient" knowledge of HTTP is why I am taking a networking class. This is my second socket program made.

Comment: I have no idea what your code looks now. A simplified version of your code works for me w/o problems. And, taking a networking class does not mean that you should not have a look at the HTTP standard, although the actual standard might be a bit too complex to start with it. Alternatively  you should at least have a closer look at actual HTTP communication instead of guessing how traffic looks like.

Comment: Okay I edited the code, however it still appears to be not working. I understand the tabbing looks off here I can't seem learn the right way to copy paste my code here. But in my program all the indentations are correct. Is there any other reasons why this code isn't working for me? When I run the program it says that the server is ready. However when I try to connect to "localhost:3000/index.html"  all I get is the error message saying the site cannot be reached, and "localhost refused to connect". (index.html is in the same directory as WebServer.py as well)

Comment: @BenYan: When I told you that line end is `\r\n` and not `\n` I did not expect you to replace `\n\n` with `\r\n` but with `\r\n\r\n`, i.e. replace each of the line ends. There must be an empty line which marks the end of the HTTP header. I urge you to read at least the Wikipedia article about the HTTP message format before doing more wrong guesswork: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Message_format

Comment: I read the article and I believe I understand the format better now... and I made the changes. I'm going through line by line going crazy trying to get this to work at the moment, yet I still can't connect to the server.

Comment: @BenYan: the server as currently shown in your question works for me, i.e. when accessing `http://127.0.0.1:3000/index.html`.  I have no idea what your problem is - are you sure that you are using the same port in server and URL you access? Note that you still have a `break` in your code so that the server exits after handling a single request. Thus make sure that it is actually running when you access the page.

Comment: So you're saying my code in the the post is working fine for you? Interesting. Does it make a difference if I'm executing the WebServer.py from the command line? Currently I'm executing from command line and then both Internet Explorer and Google Chrome won't connect to the page. Thank you for your help so far by the way, makes me realize I have a lot to learn.

Comment: Okay so I restarted my computer and ran the server and now it's working for some odd reason. Is there any possible explanation for this?

Comment: @BenYan: I don't have any explanation for it based on this description but I'm sure there would be one if one had a chance to see everything you did live.